# My bfs mum is neglecting her pets. I need advice

Tags: cats, dogs

My boyfriends mum doesn’t look after her pets and I need help

My boyfriends mum isn’t looking after her pets

So I thought I’d come here to ask people’s option. I have been with my boyfriend for almost 3 years and I have a brilliant relationship with his mum. When we first started going out she had a dog and a cat who had recently had kittens. They also had a bearded dragon which was the youngest brothers. I then noticed that this cat just kept having kittens and I was getting a bit concerned. She’s had about 5 litters now. So I said that it be best for Lola (the cat) to get spayed along with the kittens they kept. She agreed that after she had her last litter she would. Unfortunately whilst we were on holidays we came back to two dead kittens in 2 different locations. I again mentioned it would be good to get them spayed giving the reason that one of the kittens we kept was a male and we wouldn’t want inbreeding. Well, they then got fleas and got sent outside for 6 months !!!! They’re still out now and not allowed to come in as they have now got worms. I then noticed that once again Lola looked massive and that she had a lump on one of her nipples. I mentioned it to my boyfriend but he wasn’t sure what to suggest. So not only is she pregnant again, she may have a worms and a tumour as well as going to be giving birth to kittens outside. To add to this I had noticed that the springer spaniel that they have would be desperate to go out and would drink from a plant pot and eat the cat food. Not desperate to go to the bathroom but to eat. So
I have been secretly giving her small amounts of dried cat food and she eats it so fast it worrying. There’s no dog food in the house and the dog doesn’t get walked. I have tried to walk her but as she has never been walked she doesn’t know how which makes it harder to do that. I have mentioned all this to my bf but he says “what am I meant to do” so I say that they are his pets too and his responsibility as well. So I am not sure what to do. I can’t afford for the vets as much as I want to as I’m only a first year uni student, I’m going to get some dog food and claim that it’s left over from when we had ours dogs. To add on to this, the bearded dragon unfortunately died from starvation as the youngest of course didn’t look after it and the mother didn’t take the responsibility. They usually live about 8 years, he died at half that and she claimed that it was a natural death. Not only that but the youngest didn’t notice he’s even died for a good year. I love all the pets and I try do what I can for them but they’re going to end up dying it living a really rubbish life. I need some guidance that I can do myself at home as I can’t report it because she will know that it was someone in the house who reported it and every time I mention anything to her she gets
In a huge hissy fit hence why nothings been done.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about dealing with a person, not the animals, and would be better suited for Interpersonal Skills SE

Comment: Beyond that, the only advice I might have is reporting her to animal control for neglect, depending on where you live, but you're still going to need the IPS advice for dealing with the people involved. This question really isn't about the pets at the root of it.

Comment: Hi Lizzy, Like Allison wrote, we can not help you here with good advice, because we know much about animals, but less about how to handle people. Please try to focus on an aim, you want to reach with the people (to make them notice the pets more, or to move the animals to better homes) and then ask this on https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/ , another site in the stackexchange family, Maybe some moderator here could migrate it, if you reshaped it and ask for it, too :) I wish you good luck and a better life for the animals. It is the right step to think about a good live for the pets!

Comment: Hey Lizzy! I'm one of the moderators on IPS. Just letting you know that I would recommend against just copy-pasting (or migrating) your question to that site, as that would get it closed for asking 'what should I do'. The site requires questions to actually focus on solving a problem with your interpersonal skills, behaviors you use to interact well with others and reach your goals, instead of asking for general advice. Allerleirauh gave some good guidance already, it might also help you to take a look at our [meta post on writing good questions](https://ips.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3224) :)

Comment: Regarding the pregnant cat: Try contacting a local animal rescue or animal welfare organization. This one cat is already creating a problem with all her kittens and possible inbreeding and such an organization might help financially to stop the problem before it grows even bigger. Or they catch as many of the kittens as they can and try rehoming them before they become too feral.